Lazy and suspense not working for export route
I tried to lazy and suspense in my routes.js page.
import { Navigate, useRoutes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { lazy,Suspense } from 'react';

export default function Router() {
  <Suspense fallback={<DashboardAppPage/>}>
  const routes = useRoutes([
    {
      path: 'login',
      element: <LoginPage />},
    {
      path: '/dashboard',
      element: <DashboardLayout />,
      children: [
        { element: <Navigate to="/dashboard/app" />, index: true },
   
      ],
    },
   
    
    {
      element: <SimpleLayout />,
      children: [
        { element: <Navigate to="/login" />, index: true },
        { path: '404', element: <Page404 /> },
        { path: '*', element: <Navigate to="/404" /> },
      ],
    },
    {
      path: '*',
      element: <Navigate to="/404" replace />,
    },
  ]);
  </Suspense>

  return routes;
}


In the code the "Suspense tag is not working.
Parse errors in imported module './routes': Unexpected token, expected "}" (37:10) (37:10)

Your code isn't valid Javascript. Are you trying to render the Suspense component within the routes? What are you lazy loading? Can you [edit] to clarify the problem? See [mcve].

Even I am trying to find a way to implement suspense and route

The code you are working with isn't valid Javascript. The Suspense component should be rendered as part of the returned JSX that Router is rendering, e.g. that it returns.
Consider the following rewrite:
Return Suspense wrapping routes.
export default function Router() {
  const routes = useRoutes([
    { path: 'login', element: <LoginPage /> },
    {
      path: 'dashboard',
      element: <DashboardLayout />,
      children: [
        { element: <Navigate to="/dashboard/app" />, index: true }, 
      ],
    },   
    {
      element: <SimpleLayout />,
      children: [
        { element: <Navigate to="/login" />, index: true },
        { path: '404', element: <Page404 /> },
        { path: '*', element: <Navigate to="/404" /> },
      ],
    },
    {
      path: '*',
      element: <Navigate to="/404" replace />,
    },
  ]);

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<DashboardAppPage />}>
      {routes}
    </Suspense>
  );
}

